# Django: import errors from corsheaders

Tags: django

I am doing angular/django crud tutorial.  I have done in virtual env:

```
 pip install django-cors-headers
```

I believe it was successfully installed.  But when I start the server with:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the error:  'Import error:No module named djangocrud.apicorsheaders'

I added 'corsheaders' to Installed Apps and
     'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

at the top of MiddleWare in settings.py

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.  I didn't have a comma between 'corsheaders' and the preceding entry in Installed Apps.  Check closely for commas.